# Irrationality by Measure Argument

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question, real-numbers

I was wondering if the fact that the measure of the irrationals is larger than the measure of the rationals can be used for a loose argument that a given real constant is irrational.  Since almost all real numbers are irrational the probability that a truly random real number is irrational is 1.  I was wondering about numbers like the Euler Mascheroni constant which still have an unknown irrationality status.  Intuitively, one could argue constants like these are most likely irrational since almost all real numbers are irrational.  The problem with this argument is that constants like the Euler Mascheroni constant are not truly random and are the result of specific definitions which could possibly imply rationality.

An example of something similar happens with the golden ratio.  If one defines the golden ratio in terms of the golden rectangle, it may not be obvious to a non-expert that it is an algebraic number.  Since almost all real numbers are transcendental one could use the same argument to argue the golden ratio is likely transcendental.  The definition does turn out to imply it is algebraic in this case illustrating the fact that the golden ratio was never a random selection.

Historically, it seems that real constants whose rationality status is unknown do turn out to be irrational and also turn out to fall into other sets that take up almost all real numbers such as the transcendentals.  I was wondering if there were any ares of mathematics where an idea similar to this has been made rigorous.

Comment: As you say, since these constants have very special definitions, it's not clear how you can invoke general probabilistic notions.

Comment: An arbitrary real number has 0 chance to be an integer. Nonetheless, my favorite number is still 4 :)

Comment: I know you can’t directly use this argument  as the golden ratio example shows.  I was wondering if there is anything in mathematics that uses something similar.  Even though this argument is not rigorous, it seems interesting that the many of special constants which are not directly rational(algebraic) as a immediate consequence of their definition turn out to be irrational(transcendental).  I was wondering if this may be a result of a deeper pattern.

Comment: is it really possible to generate a random number? I would think not. Try imagining what a random integer from 1 through $\infty$ might look like....